# malloc.c:3097: sYSMALLOc: Assertion fails inside constructor of dynamically created object

Tags: c++, oop, malloc

I'm somewhat new to OOP with C++, so I'm hoping that I've just made some simple beginner mistake. I've got some code that is giving me seemingly inexplicable malloc errors. I've reduced my code to the smallest thing that still crashes, which is this:

MyClass.cpp:

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

#include <string>
using std::string;

class MyClass{
      string * myString1;
      string * myString2;

      int length1;
      int length2;

      vector< vector<int>* > * myVector;

   public:
      MyClass(string * a, string * b);
};

MyClass::MyClass(string * a, string * b)
: myString1(a), myString2(b)
{

   // commenting both of the lines that access the string sizes
   // makes it work

   length1 = myString1->size();

   // commenting either or both of the following lines makes
   // it work

   length2 = myString2->size();

   myVector = new vector< vector<int>* >;
}
```

MyClass.h

```
#ifndef MyClass_H
#define MyClass_H

#include <string>
using std::string;

class MyClass{
   public:
      MyClass(string * a, string * b);
};

#endif
```

test.cpp:

```
#include "../include/MyClass.h"
#include <string>
using std::string;


int main()
{
   string * A = new string("foobar");
   string * B = new string("foobaz");

   MyClass * mc = new MyClass(A, B);

   return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling like this:

```
g++ -ggdb -Wall -c src/test.cpp -o .objects/test.o
g++ -ggdb -Wall -c src/MyClass.cpp -o .objects/MyClass.o
g++ .objects/test.o .objects/MyClass.o  -ggdb -Wall -o test
```

And when I run it I get this:

```
test: malloc.c:3097: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Aborted
```

I've seen valgrind suggested as a tool to debug these kinds of problems, I wasn't able to understand anything from it's output. The output is quite long, so I've pasted it [here](http://pastebin.com/zCXu8twq).

Gdb points to the line where the new vector is created as being the problem (which is not too surprising). The full gdb output is [here](http://pastebin.com/mn0SYyee). What I find odd is that If I don't access either of the string lengths, then the new vector is created with no problem.

I'm really at a loss here, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with your error, but as a side note: You'll want to be careful about overusing pointers. For example, an object of this class will contain pointers to strings that were created in another scope. If the MyClass object outlives the scope of the strings (e.g. the strings are created on the stack and your MyClass is created with `new MyClass(&a, &b)`, as soon as that function exits, the pointers in your object will be invalid).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The major problem is that you've defined `MyClass` in two incompatible ways: in `MyClass.cpp`, it has five data members (two pointers, two integers, and another pointer), but in `MyClass.h`, and therefore in `test.cpp`, it has no data members at all. Therefore, when your `main` function calls `new MyClass(A, B)`, the system allocates only enough memory for the no-data-members version of `MyClass`, and then it invokes the constructor, which initializes data members that you didn't allocate memory for.

You need to move your class definition from `MyClass.cpp` to `MyClass.h`, and the very first line of `MyClass.cpp` should be `#include "MyClass.h"`. This will ensure that you don't have any incompatibilities, since it will cause `MyClass.cpp` to emit a compile error if you do.

Comment: Good catch, didn't even notice the double definition.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! As I said, I'm still new to c++ OOP.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared two completely different versions of `MyClass`; one in `MyClass.h`, and the other in `MyClass.cpp`. Your `main()` function in `test.cpp` sees the version from MyClass.h, and will allocate memory according to that definition, but your code in MyClass.cpp is operating on a different definition of the class.

The reason this is failing is because those two definitions have different sizes and layouts in memory.

To do this properly, you need to include the complete definition of MyClass in MyClass.h. 
i.e.

```
#ifndef MyClass_H
#define MyClass_H

#include <string>
using std::string;

class MyClass {
      string * myString1;
      string * myString2;
      int length1;
      int length2;
      vector< vector<int>* > * myVector;
   public:
      MyClass(string * a, string * b);
};

#endif
```

This is one of the key points of C++ - even the private members need to be in the publicly accessible definition of the class.

Then you need to include `MyClass.h` in `MyClass.cpp` as well as in `test.cpp`, and remove the declaration of `MyClass` from `MyClass.cpp` -- you only want the class declaration to appear in one place.

---

You also have a memory leak, because you haven't given `MyClass` a destructor where it will clean up the memory it has allocated in its constructor. A better approach to writing `new` and `delete` all over the place would be to investigate [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: Thanks, I did know that I will have memory leaks with that class, I just thought I'd omit the destructor to simplify the code in the question. I will check out std::shared_ptr though, hadn't heard of that.

Comment: `shared_ptr` is awesome; it's a reference counted smart pointer. For most usages, any time you need to allocate memory from the heap, and especially if you need to pass dynamically allocated objects around, `shared_ptr<T>` will eliminate 99% of the headaches associated with memory management.

Comment: Oh very cool - garbage collection (or something like it) for C++ basically?